# Power on AWS EC2 hosts by specifying their ansible hostnames

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2

I have inventoried my AWS EC2 hosts using the ansible Ec2 inventory plugin.

I would like to be able to power on hosts that are currently powered off, by specifying hostname patterns in ad-hoc ansible commands per usual:

```
ansible <hostname> -m <module_name> -a <module_arguments>
```

instead of having to specify instance IDs, or tag values, or regions, or whatever, in a playbook using the `amazon.aws.ec2`, which is how the doc says to do it:

```
- name: Start sandbox instances
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
    region: us-east-1
  tasks:
    - name: Start the sandbox instances
      amazon.aws.ec2:
        instance_ids: '{{ instance_ids }}'
        region: '{{ region }}'
        state: running
        wait: True
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
        assign_public_ip: yes
  roles:
    - do_neat_stuff
    - do_more_neat_stuff
```

Is there a way to specify hostname patterns to power on desired instances using the amazon.aws.ec2 module (not SSH, which obviously doesn't work when hosts are off), without having to also use instance ids, tags, etc (whether directly in the playbook or as variables in files)?